# Cloudflare - normal TCP connection "bad request"

Tags: tcp, tcpclient, cloudflare

This question is only related to Cloudflare Proxy

> Trials:

If I try to establish a connection to mydomain.com:8443 through the browser it works
But if I try the same but using an ownmade TCP program, it disconnects before hitting the actual server.

Note that using the ownmade TCP program works if I turn off the orange cloud (proxy)

> Errors:

So I used wireshark to see what happen and it turns out Cloudflare blocks the connection with error code 400 Bad Request

> Thoughts/Questions:

Is there any settings in Cloudflare I can fiddle around with to forward it to the server regardless if it is a "bad request" (while keeping orange clouded proxy on)? Or am I forced to re-write the program to start a Websocket instead?

Comment: AFAIK, Cloudflare will respond with a 400 and/or close the connection as soon as it detects that the incoming request doesn't look like an HTTP(S) request. What are you trying to do?

Comment: It's not a HTTP(S) request, and doesn't look like one either. Trying to get my clients to connect through Cloudflares proxy to keep my servers IP protected.

Comment: Normal Cloudflare is not a generic TCP proxy. It is only a proxy for HTTP and HTTPS. Anything else will be considered bad data. There is [Cloudflare Spectrum](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/cloudflare-spectrum/) if you want generic TCP or UDP.